# jQuery canvas addImage dynamically

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have a canvas element and I need to add images dynamically.

```
function draw(){
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage("img/image1.jpg",0,0,200,200);
}
```

The html code is the next:

```
<div id="divCanvas">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="322px" height="450px">Canvas not suported</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? To the best of my knowledge, the code you posted in your question should work

Comment: When I click a button it must insert a new image into the canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QS653/)**

```
var startX = 0,
    startY = 0;

$('#clicker').click(function(){
    draw($('#testImage'));
});

function draw(image){
    image = image.get(0);
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(image,startX,startY,20,20);
    startY+=20;
}
```

Used jQuery because you have it tagged as such. Not sure what issue your running into exactly, but to get the actual `DOM` element to draw onto the canvas you have to use `.get()`.

Comment: I try to use your exemple but don't work. Faild when drawImage is called